# CSS Grid when header is full width but content is constrained

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I am fairly new to CSS Grid, and I have the following design that I drew up in Adobe XD.

[image: design]

When designing the above, I split my page into a 10 column grid, I wish to use a grid named templates to achieve the above layout, but I am struggling to find a neat way.

My initial thought was to do this:

[image]

But I believe this involves me creating empty divs for the left and right (10/2). Not nice!

I haven't drawn the rows, cause I think I have those figured out, it'll be 3 rows (breadcrumbs, title, content-with-meta).

What is the better way? I've created a [codepen](https://codepen.io/Ciwan/pen/ejJgGN) with my current HTML structure.

```
<div class="deity-details">
  <header>
    <div class="breadcrumbs">
      <a href="#">Home</a> /
      <a href="#">Deities</a> /
      <a href="#">Athena</a>
    </div>
    <h1 class="deity-name">Athena</h1>
  </header>

  <section class="deity-description">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus mollis commodo dictum. Nulla facilisi. Quisque urna ipsum, interdum eu posuere consectetur, dictum at metus. Integer id lorem quis purus tincidunt malesuada quis non ligula. Pellentesque congue pharetra nibh eu mattis. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vivamus dictum urna urna, eget tincidunt ligula consectetur ut. Aliquam erat volutpat.</p>

<p>Etiam interdum iaculis pellentesque. Suspendisse potenti. Aliquam quis tortor tincidunt, maximus odio et, tempor eros. Curabitur a purus mauris. Sed in consequat augue. Mauris placerat ullamcorper congue. Sed elementum ligula tellus, vitae mattis diam tristique sed. Duis luctus tempor justo non ornare. Nam vel lobortis orci. Donec hendrerit porttitor consectetur. Curabitur non nunc laoreet, sagittis massa vitae, rhoncus turpis. Phasellus non scelerisque nibh, id feugiat risus. Cras elementum varius ex, vel accumsan risus laoreet eu. Morbi suscipit turpis nec dapibus fermentum.</p>
  </section>

  <section class="deity-meta">
    <div class="attributes">
      <div class="attribute">
        <label>Origin</label>
        <h4>Greek</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="attribute">
        <label>Aliases</label>
        <h4>None</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="attribute">
        <label>Sex</label>
        <h4>Female</h4>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
</div>
```

Comment: https://cloudfour.com/thinks/breaking-out-with-css-grid-layout/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`grid-template-areas` & `grid-area` might not be needed if you want to add some content later, you can use a `grid-template-columns`*(reusable on header and eventually on a footer later)* and set `grid-column` to children:

```css
.deity-details,
header {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(10, 1fr)
}

header {
  grid-column: 1 /span 10;
  background: green;
}

.breadcrumbs,
.deity-name,
.deity-description {
  grid-column: 3 /span 3;
  background: green;
}

.deity-meta {
  grid-column: 7 / span 2;
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="deity-details">
  <header>
    <div class="breadcrumbs">
      <a href="#">Home</a> /
      <a href="#">Deities</a> /
      <a href="#">Athena</a>
    </div>
    <h1 class="deity-name">Athena</h1>
  </header>

  <section class="deity-description">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus mollis commodo dictum. Nulla facilisi. Quisque urna ipsum, interdum eu posuere consectetur, dictum at metus. Integer id lorem quis purus tincidunt malesuada quis non ligula. Pellentesque
      congue pharetra nibh eu mattis. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vivamus dictum urna urna, eget tincidunt ligula consectetur ut. Aliquam erat volutpat.</p>

    <p>Etiam interdum iaculis pellentesque. Suspendisse potenti. Aliquam quis tortor tincidunt, maximus odio et, tempor eros. Curabitur a purus mauris. Sed in consequat augue. Mauris placerat ullamcorper congue. Sed elementum ligula tellus, vitae mattis
      diam tristique sed. Duis luctus tempor justo non ornare. Nam vel lobortis orci. Donec hendrerit porttitor consectetur. Curabitur non nunc laoreet, sagittis massa vitae, rhoncus turpis. Phasellus non scelerisque nibh, id feugiat risus. Cras elementum
      varius ex, vel accumsan risus laoreet eu. Morbi suscipit turpis nec dapibus fermentum.</p>
  </section>

  <section class="deity-meta">
    <div class="attributes">
      <div class="attribute">
        <label>Origin</label>
        <h4>Greek</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="attribute">
        <label>Aliases</label>
        <h4>None</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="attribute">
        <label>Sex</label>
        <h4>Female</h4>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
</div>
```

There is no need of empty elements on a grid CSS.

---

Your pen forked to play with : https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/mjVWqY

You can use this as a reminder : https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/